# Open File in Android External Storage and read JSON String

Tags: android, json, file, android-external-storage

I'm trying to get a JSON string from a file saved under the downloads folder of an Android device. Now I'm able to get a path to this just fine using a filebrowser provided [here](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser).

I attempted to use the idion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file) to open the file and read out a string. (evidently Android doesn't use Java 7? I am unable to use the answer from this question, the only Files class I find is under android.provider.MediaStore)

In any case, I get (sort of) the JSON string using the idiom from the question. Problem is I can't use the output with GSON (error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1)

I suspect it's because what I'm getting back from the file to string function looks like this:

```
����z������9>{
   "chEqEnable": [
   [
      true,
      true,
... etc ...
```

Also occasionaly values for say, a boolean looks like:

```
z������      true,
```

instead of

```
true,
```

Is there some better way when dealing with Android and external storage, to take my file and read a JSON string from it, abberation free?

For reference, here is what my implementation of the idiom from the other question looks like:

```
public static String file2String(String filePath) throws IOException
{

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line = null;

    try{
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

    String returnStr = stringBuilder.toString();
    return returnStr;
}
```

When I write a file to external storage I use this

```
public static String ExportTuning(Context context, String fileName, String json)
    {
        File path;
        if(fileName.contains(".rfts")) {
            path = GetDocumentsPath(fileName);
        } else {
            path = GetDocumentsPath(fileName+".rfts");
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            ObjectOutput strOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            strOut.writeUTF(json);
//            strOut.writeChars(json); // this just causes a ton of gibberish when I read the file back
            strOut.close();
            fileOut.close();

            String[] paths = new String[]{path.getAbsolutePath()};
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, paths, null, null);

            return "Save Successful";
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some better way when dealing with Android and external storage, to take my file and read a JSON string from it, abberation free?

Your primary problem lies in the `ExportTuning()` method. You are not writing out JSON. You are writing out a Java object to an `ObjectOutputStream`. If you want to write JSON, get rid of the `ObjectOutputStream` and use something that writes text, not objects (e.g., `PrintWriter`). Please note that you can examine JSON files using your favorite text editor, or `cat`, or whatever, to see if it contains what you expect.

In terms of parsing the JSON later, delete all your read-into-a-string code, create a `Reader` object (e.g., an `InputStreamReader`), and [pass that to `fromJson()`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: Finally managed to get the file off the tablet (Never buy an ASUS!) And yeah looks like it's all byte code. I'll give your solution a shot.